# Four pictures sharing a corner : alternative HTML+CSS layout?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I am trying to setup four image panels with a common corner.  Images are randomly picked and often have different dimensions.

I managed to get a correct layout using absolute positioning of pictures inside relative cells of a table :

```css
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }

  td {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  img {
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .top img {
    bottom: 0; 
  }
  
  .bottom img {
    top: 0;
  }
    
  .left img {
    right: 0;
  }
 
  .right img {
    left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="top left">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
    </td>
    <td class="top right">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bottom left">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/100"/>
    </td>
    <td class="bottom right">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However `td`s have a zero height because of the absolute positioning.  As a consequence, I struggle to place the whole table at the correct position inside the whole page.

I am wondering if there is another way to achieve this layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split this into rows, then into cells and all that with a help of a flexbox.

```css
.row
{
  display: flex;
}

.cell
{
  width: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.move-left
{
  margin-right: auto;
}

.move-right
{
  margin-left: auto;
}

.move-bottom
{
  margin-top: auto;
}

.move-top
{
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="cell">
    <img class="move-right move-bottom" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200"/>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <img class="move-left move-bottom" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="cell">
    <img class="move-right move-top" src="http://placekitten.com/100/300"/>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <img class="move-left move-top" src="http://placekitten.com/400/200"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try flexbox. https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

```css
        .Aligner {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        } 
        .Aligner-item {
            max-width: 50%;
        }
        .flex-item img{
            vertical-align:top;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="Aligner"> 
        <div class="Aligner-item">
            <div class="flex-item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
                 <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Aligner"> 
        <div class="Aligner-item">
            <div class="flex-item">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/300" />
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll accept CyberAP's answer rather than yours because it has better behaviour when downsizing the browser window (as can be seen when running the snippet, on small displays your solution doesn't scale properly, I even thought it didn't work before I expand the snippet full page).